# Jboss Communications link failure with mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss6.x, hornetq

I am, use Hibernate to map my objects into a MySql DB. At specific point of time MDB consumer stopped consuming messages from HornetQ and following exception occurs an unpredictable period of time. I am using Jboss as 6.0.0 Final with default hornetq version.

**Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure**

Below are my c3p0 configurations:

```
minPoolSize=25
initialPoolSize=25
maxPoolSize=1000
acquireIncrement=5
maxIdleTime=3600
idleConnectionTestPeriod=500
maxIdleTimeExcessConnections=300 
maxConnectionAge=3600
preferredTestQuery=select 1
maxStatements=0
numHelperThreads=10
statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads=1
maxAdministrativeTaskTime=60
acquireRetryAttempts=0
AcquireRetryDelay=3000
BreakAfterAcquireFailure=false
```

Thanks, 
Veera

Comment: i want to update one more issue that my MDBConsumer stopped consuming messages after some time and I try to monitor this c3p0 connection pool (Mbean) using VisualVM tool in that i can see "numConnections" is keep reducing. i can see : numConnections:25 & numIdleConnections:25 & numBusyConnections : 0). If it is the case where i did wrong. Can any one suggest please.

Comment: I just resolved error "Communications link failure with mysql" by increasing   wait_timeout value in mysql.  But after some time my connection pool size is reducing still facing this issue. Can any one help ???